# How do I convert unicode from an HTML input to a greek character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, input

How do I convert unicode from an HTML input to a greek character in javascript? The first example does not work, but the second does.

```
var str = input.value;       \u03B1 (typed into input box)
console.log(str);            \u03B1

var str = "\u03B1";          assigned directly
console.log(str);            α
```

Comment: Why would you use such an input method? If I had to use something like that, as a user, I’d rather just launch CharMap, select the characters there, and do cut and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert unicode literals in strings to actual characters you can just run them though [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```
var str = '\\u03B1\\u03B2\\u03B3\\u03B4'; // "\u03B1\u03B2\u03B3\u03B4"

str.replace(/\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/g, function (m, $1) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt($1, 16));
}); // "αβγδ"
```

Answer (score 3):

The backslash is escaping in the second variable `str` - in the first value, if input.value was `\u03B1`, it would ACTUALLY be the same as `var str = "\\U03B1"` to invalidate the backslash by escaping it.

If you want to evaluate the escaped character in the field, you can do so like this:

```
var str = input.value.replace("\\u", "");
str = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str, 16));
```

This works because you are parsing an integer from everything after \u and passing that into `fromCharCode`. Character codes are in integers - you are parsing that code from the original `\u23B1` code.